# Multi-role check using rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

Is it possible to do a multi-role check - `user.has_role?(:admin, :moderator)`  ...which hopefully does one query to the DB vs doing `user.has_role?(:admin) && user.has_role?`(:moderator) which obviously involves going to DB twice.

https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/234

Answer (score 2):

No, right now you can't pass such options.

```
user.has_role?(:admin, :moderator)
```

If you want to save yourself from performing multiple queries, you can do something like

```
(user.roles & [:admin, :moderator]).present?
```

Answer (score 2):

rolify has `has_any_role?` and `has_all_roles?` methods that do this quite readably. `has_any_role?` only hits the DB once, but `has_all_roles?` looks like it iterates over the arguments calling `has_role?` so that wouldn't entirely address your concern about hitting the DB multiple times (it does stop when it hits the first negative result, which is better than nothing).

It looks to me like you could check if a user had both roles in one query with:

```
user.roles.where("name IN (?, ?)", "admin", "moderator").size > 1
```

That doesn't work if the user could have the same role on different resources, but you get the idea. The other problem is that it hard codes the number of roles you check. You could get around that by constructing the arguments list and using `send` but it would be kind of ugly. Alternatively, if you knew that the values you were checking for were safe, you could put them in an array and do:

```
roles_to_check = ["admin", "moderator"]
user.roles.where(name: roles_to_check).size >= roles_to_check.size
```